# Fetching total count of matching items in paged Mongo aggregate query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've seen basic questions on SO but not able to make it work in my case. Here's my query:

```
return Order.aggregateAsync([{
     $match: { status: { $ne: 'incomplete' } }
   }, {
     $unwind: '$items'
   }, {
     $match: {... }
   },

   {
     $limit: limit
   }, {
     $skip: skip
   }, {
     $group: {
       _id: '$items._id',
       product: {
         $first: '$items.product'
       },
       qty: {
         $first: '$items.qty'
       },
       ordered: {
         $first: '$ordered'
       }

     }
   }, {
     $sort: { 'ordered': -1 }
   },
 ])...
```

How can I return from this something such as:

```
{ 
  items: [array of items by page/limit],
  total: total items in db that match $match
}
```

I've tried adding this after $match:

```
 {
   $group: {
     _id: null,
     items: { $push: '$items' },
     count: { $sum: 1 }
   }
 },
```

But it seems to not use limit then.

Sample data:

```
[{
    _id:ObjectID
    status: 'incomplete'
    ordered: Date,
    items: [{
      _id: ObjectID
      qty: 100,
      product: ObjectID
    }, {
      _id: ObjectID
      qty: 10,
      product: ObjectID
    }]
}, {
    _id:ObjectID
    status: 'incomplete'
    ordered: Date,
    items: [{
      _id: ObjectID
      qty: 200,
      product: ObjectID
    }]
}]
```

I want to return all the items, grouped by items as a paged query (limit,skip):

```
 [{
  _id: ObjectID
  qty: 100,
  product: ObjectID
}, {
  _id: ObjectID
  qty: 10,
  product: ObjectID
}, {
  _id: ObjectID
  qty: 200,
  product: ObjectID
}]
```

As well as the total count (3) of all items that match.

So:

```
result = {
  docs: items array above,
  total: 3
```

Comment: please show your sample input data and sample output data for  what u want

Comment: @karthi added sample data

Answer (score 0):

you try this query , its useful to you , and it will give you result for u want

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([

   { $unwind: '$items'},
   {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "",
            "doc": { $push: "$items" },
            "total":{ $sum: 1}

         }
     },
    { $project : { doc : 1 , total : 1,_id:0 } } 
])
```

output

```
{
            "doc" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 11,
                    "qty" : 100,
                    "product" : 12
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 111,
                    "qty" : 10,
                    "product" : 112
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 21,
                    "qty" : 100,
                    "product" : 22
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 211,
                    "qty" : 10,
                    "product" : 212
                }
            ],
            "total" : 4.0000000000000000
        }
```

Comment: I tried something like that before. The problem is that I use `skip` and `limit` which do not work after I have grouped things and if used before they affect the count.